# Is there a free MySQL manager with a visual query builder for Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need a free MySQL manager with a visual query builder.

I used to use EMS manager for MySQL in Windows but since I'm trying to be a Ubuntu user now, I need another tool with a visual query builder to save me time of creating queries.

A lot of posts online mention that MySQL Workbench has a visual query builder but I couldn't find it. All it has is an ERR from database which is making a reverse engineering for any database.

I need something like that to create a query, not ERR. Something like:

[image: Visual query builder]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenOffice / LibreOffice has a [graphical query designer](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Query_Design) in its database application.

Examples:

[image]

Comment: I'm beginning to like Ubuntu already :) , it even can connect to remote database. Freeeeeeeeeeeeedoooooooooooom

Comment: Does this support MySQL though Rinzwind?

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes. LO/OO has a mysql connector

Comment: Also it supports postgresql db via `libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql` package